# How to add OAuth connection settings without Azure Bot Service?

Tags: c#, azure, oauth, botframework

I'm adding authentication to a bot built with Bot Framework SDK v4 (C#) that will work with Microsoft Teams. I've been following [add authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-sample#microsoft-azure-active-directory-azure-ad-v2) and [add SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso-bots#update-the-azure-portal-with-the-oauth-connection) tutorials, trying to get it to work. Both of these hyperlinks jump to a requirement I am stuck on, which is to add OAuth connection settings through the Azure Bot Service. I don't have a subscription with Azure and would prefer to avoid it. I just don't want to deal with a subscription to all these services when I need a tiny portion of it. I'm also going to publish the bot on a local server, not to Azure, and I'm pretty sure I only need a [standard channel](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bot-services/#pricing), which should be free.

The tutorials also explain that I need to use Azure Bot Service to generate a Microsoft app id and an app password. It turns out those values can be obtained through a normal app registration, [which I need anyways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso-bots#register-your-app-through-the-azure-ad-portal), in Azure AD. They are just app Id and client secret. This is making me wonder if that OAuth connection setting can be created outside of an Azure subscription as well.

As of now, running the [46.teams-auth](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth) sample throws me an error explaining that I need a valid `connectionName` which is obtained by creating an OAuth connection setting.

All I'm trying to do is to implement authentication to a bot that will be used in Teams. So my questions are the following:

1. What even is the OAuth connection setting and is it necessary to create?
2. Is it not enough to register the bot application in Azure AD? It's just an API.
3. Is there any way to create the OAuth connection setting outside of an Azure subscription?

I've already used the [Developer Portal](https://dev.teams.microsoft.com/apps), Azure AD, [Bot Framework website](https://dev.botframework.com/bots), and [ngrok](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-sample#testing-the-bot-locally-in-teams) to successfully test my bot in Teams. Adding authentication is the last step.

Comment: You are send HTTP (or HTTPS).  The OAUTH are simply HTTP Headers added to the request.  Only servers that require OAUTH do you need to add the headers.

Comment: So since the bot sends requests to the Teams servers. Does Teams need the OAuth headers and can I create them outside of an Azure subscription?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow?force_isolation=true